# Insert a string at a specific position (fixed length file)

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, ksh

I'm trying to insert a string "abcd" at the position of 80 in each rows of a fixed length file.

**Input file**

```
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 234235235321      MISS WAN
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 324556346366      MISS NISCH
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 547478657588      MISS RACHEL
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000009781 313156475788      MR & MRS ROCK
```

The **length of each records** are

```
awk '{print length}' temp.txt
74
76
77
79
```

I wasn't able to insert data at 80 and I've tried **the below commands**

```
sed "s/.\{80\}/&abcd/" test.txt
awk -vFS="" -vOFS="" '{$80=$80"abcd"}1' test.txt
```

I thought that I should first increase the length of the records so then I can use the above commands..

**To insert spaces**

```
sed -e "s/.\{75\}/&              /g" test.txt
sed 's/$/        /" test.txt
```

**Inside a loop**

```
while read line
do
printf "$line        " >>temp.txt
done <test.txt
```

Most of the time the above spaces get amended with the next lines and **lost some of the contents** as shown below..

```
4044046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS WAN
    046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS NISCH
    046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS RACHEL
2011888360797600140053062257440    00000009781 851011576287      MR & MRS ROCK
```

**Expected answer:**

```
4044046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS WAN       abcd
4044046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS NISCH     abcd
4044046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS RACHEL    abcd
2011888360797600140053062257440    00000009781 851011576287      MR & MRS ROCK  abcd
```

Any guidelines towards the right answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: curious ... do you need to worry about lines that are >= 80 characters in length and if so, what do you do with the characters that currently reside in positions 80+?

Comment: Hi @markp, there're no chars at the position 80 right now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution as per OP's requirement for adding spaces as per length of 80:
In case you have control M characters in your Input_files and you want to remove them then use:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

then run following code:

```
awk -v var="80" '{printf("%s%"var-length($0)+1"s%s\n",$0,OFS,"abcd")}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution(more generic one):*** Could you please try following, this solution will look for maximum length of the line in whole Input_file and will add spaces according to it and newly entered last field will be in same alignment with all other lines.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  len=length($0)>len?length($0):len
  next
}
{
  printf("%s%"len-length($0)+1"s%s\n",$0,OFS,"abcd")
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

a simpler `awk`

```
$ awk '{printf "%-80s%s\n",$0,"abcd"}' file

1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 234235235321      MISS WAN       abcd
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 324556346366      MISS NISCH     abcd
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 547478657588      MISS RACHEL    abcd
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000009781 313156475788      MR & MRS ROCK  abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `gnu awk` command:

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' -v p='80' -v s='abcd' '{
    pad=""; for (i=length(); i<=p; i++) pad=pad " "; print $0 pad s}' file
```

```
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 234235235321      MISS WAN        abcd
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 324556346366      MISS NISCH      abcd
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000003088 547478657588      MISS RACHEL     abcd
1212121212121212121213231232345    00000009781 313156475788      MR & MRS ROCK   abcd
```

Note use `-v RS='\r?\n'` which sets record separator as optional `\r` followed by `\n`. This to address case when input file has DOS line breaks.

For loop starts from length of each line to desired position (being passed from command line in variable `p`) and appends a space in `pad` variable. Finally we print each row followed by padded space and new string.

Comment: Didn't get the right one...
`
 awk -v p='80' -v s='abcd' '{
>     pad=""; for (i=length(); i<=p; i++) pad=pad " "; print $0 pad s}' temp.txt
       abcd21212121213231232345    00000003088 234235235321      MISS WAN
     abcd2121212121213231232345    00000003088 324556346366      MISS NISCH
    abcd12121212121213231232345    00000003088 547478657588      MISS RACHEL
  abcd1212121212121213231232345    00000009781 313156475788      MR & MRS ROCK
`

Comment: Here is a working demo of above code: https://ideone.com/zO35sN Make sure your input file doesn't have DOS line ending. If it does then use `dos2unix` to convert into Unix file first.

Comment: You can also use this command for a file with DOS line endings: **`awk -v RS='\r?\n' -v p='80' -v s='abcd' '{pad=""; for (i=length(); i<=p; i++) pad=pad " "; print $0 pad s}' file`**

Comment: thanks mate. **awk -v RS='\r?\n' -v p='80' -v s='abcd' '{pad=""; for (i=length(); i<=p; i++) pad=pad " "; print $0 pad s}' file** did the magic.

Comment: Glad to know it worked, as I was suspecting your input file had DOS line breaks causing original answer to give you unexpected output.

Comment: Great.  Anubhava's anubhava.  Thnaks again. :)

Comment: Hi Anubhava, could you please update the answer in your answer section?  Also if you could give some explanation through the utilization it would be great.

Comment: Have added explanation in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, combining karakfa's awk line, and the use of GNU `wc` to get the maximum line length.

```
file="./your_file"

awk -v sp=4 -v max="$(wc -L "$file")" '{printf "%-"max+sp"s%s\n",$0,"abcd"}' "$file"
```

The `-v` options initialize variables `max` with the maximum line length in the file, and `sp` for the number of spaces to use after the max line length.

Output:

```
4044046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS WAN         abcd
    046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS NISCH       abcd
    046160710301740053062257440    00000003088 850052246976      MISS RACHEL      abcd
2011888360797600140053062257440    00000009781 851011576287      MR & MRS ROCK    abcd
```

Comment: Hi, we're not specifying the position here, are we?

Comment: @SanthoshRam: This version specifies the position to be the length of the longest line + 4 . That is what the two `-v` options do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you get stuck using
`sed "s/$/        /" test.txt` and `sed "s/.\{80\}/&abcd/" test.txt`.
How did you combine them? You don't want `-i` for the first command, that would modify the inputfile.
Incorrect is

```
# error, did you try this:
sed "s/$/        /" test.txt | sed "s/.\{80\}/&abcd/" test.txt
```

The second `sed` will not look at the output of the first command, but will start with the original `test.txt`.
You can combine them (I also used single quotes) with

```
sed 's/$/        /' test.txt | sed 's/.\{80\}/&abcd/'
or shorter
sed 's/$/        /;s/.\{80\}/&abcd/' test.txt
```

The result might look good, but you can have additional spaces after `abcd`. Better is

```
sed -r 's/$/        /;s/(.{80}).*/\1abcd/' test.txt
```

The first part of the comand is ugly.
You can write your own loop like

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf "%-80sabcd\n" "${line}"
done < test.txt
```

This is a difficult method where you can use the simple `awk` given by @karakfa.